# How to count the number of steel rods in a video

Tags: python, opencv

I need to count the number of steel rods , in Python using opencv for the following image.

[Image with the steel rods at the center](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZBxTU.jpg)
I have initially converted the image to grayscale,then used erode function followed with canny edge function to detect the edges as shown below.
[image after canny edge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N43RX.png)
Later find contours and used bounding rotated rectangle to count the rods.  I am not able to get the correct count.

```
kernel = np.ones((4,4),np.uint8)
erosion = cv2.erode(gray,kernel,iterations = 1)
cv2.imshow('Erode',erosion)
canny=cv2.Canny(erosion,100,200)
cv2.imshow('Canny',canny)
kernele=np.array([[0,1,1,0],[0,1,1,0],[0,1,1,0],[0,1,1,0]],np.uint8)
dilation = cv2.dilate(canny,kernele,iterations = 1)
cv2.imshow('dilate',dilation)
c,cnt,h=cv2.findContours(dilation,cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
if cnt:
    i=0
    for cnt in contours:
        rect = cv2.minAreaRect(cnt)
        box = cv2.boxPoints(rect)
        box = np.int0(box)
        if rect[1][0]>1 and rect[1][0]<15:  #width of rod
           i+=1
```

Kindly suggest what to modify or how to get the count.
Thank You

[Next Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wKNNW.png)

Comment: Have a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38632224

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of finding edges and then going by width, there is this alternative way that you can try.

I assume your image setup is constant and hence you can crop the region containing the rods (it would be very difficult otherwise).

[image]

Adaptive threshold the image with appropriate size and constant.

[image]

Then choose 100 random rows in the image and count the number of black or white strips in it.

[image]

Find the median of these 100 rows and subtract an appropriate condition to eliminate the wrong border counts (the white strip before the first rod and after the last rod)

Code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from random import randint
from itertools import groupby

img = cv2.imread('img.jpg',0)
rod_count = []
rows, cols =img.shape[:2]
th2 = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(img,255,cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C,\
                    cv2.THRESH_BINARY,11, 2)

count = 100
while( count!=0 ):

    count = count-1
    random_row = randint(0, rows-1)

    arr = th2[random_row:random_row+1, :]
    arr2 = np.array(arr)[0].tolist()
    temp = [a[0] for a in groupby(arr2)]
    b = sum(x == 0 for x in temp)
    rod_count.append(b)


print np.median(rod_count)-2
```

**Output:** 15

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @I.Newton am working on a video file, The image mentioned above is  just a print screen of the running video, I have cropped the image containing only rods, I tried the above code, it works for an image but when used with a video and applied on a specific frame it is throwing the following error  -->  th2 = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(cropped,255,cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C,cv2.THRESH_BINARY,11, 2)cv2.error: D:\Build\OpenCV\opencv-3.3.1\modules\imgproc\src\thresh.cpp:1520: error: (-215) src.type() == (((0) & ((1 << 3) - 1)) + (((1)-1) << 3)) in function cv::adaptiveThreshold

Comment: The function adaptive threshold works for gray images. You need to convert the  image to gray scale using `img = cv2.cvtColor( img, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY )` before passing to the function.

Comment: Thank You , its working , I am getting the correct count.  Isn't it possible to count the rods with the morphology, canny techniques ? any suggestions on refining the above code

Comment: Its little difficult to work with canny edges, hough lines etc then removing the noise and all. Easiest is to work with the arrays like above. Do consider upvoting or accepting this as answer if it helped.

Comment: I tried with the above logic with the different image , I have included the new image in the question at the bottom as Next Image, it gives a wrong count. Is it because the rods are very closely placed or illumination problem or should I refine the image , kindly suggest on what to be done @I.Newton

Comment: Its because of illumination problem. You need to adjust the parameters 11,2 of `th2` to address that. Or try contrast stretching, CLAHE. That should fix it.