# Count Objects In Image

Tags: python, image-processing

i want to count the number of objects in images using python 
this is my code but it returns only 1 
i'm using contours to draw circle on the objects

```
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np 
kernel = np.ones((5,5), np.uint8)
img = cv2.imread('/home/mfp/Desktop/images/coins.png')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
mean = cv2.blur(gray , (7,7))
closing = cv2.morphologyEx(mean, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)
opening = cv2.morphologyEx(closing, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)


ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(opening, 127, 255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
im2, contours, hierarchy =cv2.findContours(thresh,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
i =0
for cnt in contours:
cv2.drawContours(img, [cnt], 0, (0, 0, 255), 3)
x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
if x>30 and x<60 and y>40 and y<80:
    i=i+1
    #cv2.rectangle(img, (x,y), (x+w,y+h), (0,0,255), 2)

elif x>60 and x<120 and y>80 and y<160:
    i=i+1
    #cv2.rectangle(img, (x,y), (x+w,y+h), (0,0,255), 2)
print(i)    


cv2.imshow('Threshold', thresh)
cv2.imshow('Image', img)

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: 1- format your code. 2- explain how it is supposed to work. 3- share what the input image is (the local path on your machine is irrelevant).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to count objects in image using python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38619382/how-to-count-objects-in-image-using-python)

Comment: Provide the image to analyze

Answer (score 0):

Check the result of your open and close functions to see if your objects are touching each other as a result of this process. This might cause them to be connected and hence identified as one whole contour. Also, sort the contours obtained based on area before you draw contours or do anything else. It helps avoid choosing too small/too large contours that might be detected. Need your input sample image to tell any further!