# How can i count segments in an image in python?

Tags: python-3.x, image-processing

I am new to image processing and python. You might've seen my amateur codes on this site in the last couple of days.

I am trying to count the number of trees using aerial images. This is my code:

```
from PIL import Image
import cv2
import numpy as np
from skimage import io, filters, measure
from scipy import ndimage

img = Image.open("D:\\Texture analysis\\K-2.jpg")
row, col = img.size

hsvimg = img.convert('HSV')
hsvimg.mode = 'RGB'
hsvimg.save('newImage2.jpg')

npHSI = np.asarray(hsvimg)                  #Convert HSI Image to np image

blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(npHSI, (45, 45), 5)

assert isinstance(blur, np.ndarray)         ##############################
assert len(blur.shape) == 3                 #Convert np Image to HSI Image
assert blur.shape[2] == 3                   ##############################

hsiBlur = Image.fromarray(blur, 'RGB')
hsiBlur.save('hsiBlur.jpg')                 #Save the blurred image

## Read
img = cv2.imread("D:\\Texture analysis\\hsiBlur.jpg")

## convert to hsv
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

#Threshold the image and segment the trees
mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, (36, 25, 25), (70, 255,255))
imask = mask>0
green = np.zeros_like(img, np.uint8)
green[imask] = img[imask]

## save 
cv2.imwrite("green.png", green)

#Count the number of trees
im = io.imread('green.png', as_grey=True)
val = filters.threshold_otsu(im)
drops = ndimage.binary_fill_holes(im < val)
labels = measure.label(drops)
print(labels.max())
```

Original image:
[image: K-2.jpg]

HSI  image with gaussian filter:
[image: hsiBlur.jpg]

Segmented image:
[image: green.png]

The last part of the code returns `7`, which is a wrong output. The value should be above 50. How can I properly count the number of green segments in the final segmented image?

**EDIT**

I converted `green.png` to binary and applied erosion with a `3x3 filter` and `iterated it 7 times` to remove the noise.
This is what I did at the end. I followed this [stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38619382/how-to-count-objects-in-image-using-python)

```
##save
cv2.imwrite("green.png", green)

#Convert to grayscale
gray = np.dot(green[...,:3], [0.299, 0.587, 0.114])
cv2.imwrite("grayScale.jpg", gray)

#Binarize the grayscale image
ret,bin_img = cv2.threshold(gray,127,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
cv2.imwrite("bin_img.jpg", bin_img)

#Erosion to remove the noise
kernel = np.ones((3, 3),np.uint8)
erosion = cv2.erode(gray, kernel, iterations = 7)
cv2.imwrite("erosion.jpg", erosion)

#Count the number of trees
finalImage = cv2.imread('erosion.jpg')
finalImage = cv2.cvtColor(finalImage, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(finalImage, 127, 255, 1)
im2, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
for cnt in contours:
    cv2.drawContours(finalImage,[cnt],0,(0,0,255),1)
```

**Saurav** mentioned in his answer ***... size of "contours" will give you the count***. This `print(contour.size())`gives an error and `print(contour)` just prints a long 2D array. How can i get the size of contour?

PS. I didn't upload the grayscale, binary and eroded image because i felt that the images were already taking too much space, I can still upload them if anyone wants to.

Comment: check findContours in opencv('cv2' that you imported)

Comment: you might want to check if a erode+dilatate on your segmented gives you better results by removing small green specks bevore counting - not sure if that is a valid approach.

Comment: @PatrickArtner, indeed. Morphological operations could be used to eliminate the 'noise' and accentuate the 'target' blobs. Such operations could possibly also be used to reduce the trees that are lumped together through erosion, into single independent blobs. Although what parameters one uses for these erosion/dilation operations, would probably leave the resultant code 'not robust' for general tree recognition, i.e. it would only find trees in this image then! More on Morphological operations:[here](https://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/courses/compsci773s1c/lectures/ImageProcessing-html/topic4.htm)

Answer (score 1):

I've found `52` trees with that script:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont

image = Image.open('04uX3.jpg')
pixels = image.load()
size = image.size
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)
font = ImageFont.truetype('arial', 60)
i = 1
for x in range(0, size[0], 100):
    for y in range(0, size[1], 100):
        if pixels[x, y][1] > 200:
            draw.text((x, y), str(i), (255, 0, 0), font=font)
            i += 1
image.save('result.png')
```

You can see that some trees weren't detected and some non-trees were detected. So this is very rough calculation:

[image: trees detected]

Answer (score 0):

I know its a bit old question, but today we have SAM (Segmenting Anything Model) and even better a SAM specified in geospatial images. https://github.com/opengeos/segment-geospatial