# How to count how many white "balls" there are in an image with Opencv Python?

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I have this image and I´m trying to count how many white "balls" there are

[image: Imagem]

I´m trying this code below and get this result

[image: Result]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
img = cv2.imread('MASK.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
img = cv2.resize(img,(700,700))
img = cv2.subtract(255, img)

detector = cv2.SimpleBlobDetector_create()

 # Detect the blobs in the image
 keypoints = detector.detect(img)
 print(len(keypoints))


 imgKeyPoints = cv2.drawKeypoints(img, keypoints, np.array([]), (0,0,255), 
 cv2.DRAW_MATCHES_FLAGS_DRAW_RICH_KEYPOINTS)

 cv2.imshow("Keypoints", imgKeyPoints)
 cv2.waitKey(0)

 cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: search for `blob detection`

Comment: Did you try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38619382/how-to-count-objects-in-image-using-python

Comment: Yes Demi, but is not working.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please give more information if you want others to help you

Comment: I posted what I´m trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some preprocessing to isolate the blobs become counting them can help. Here's an approach:

- Convert image to grayscale
- Otsu's threshold
- Morph open to remove noise
- Find contours and sum blobs

---

After converting to grayscale, we Otsu's threshold to get a binary image

[image]

Next we morph close with a `cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE` kernel to remove noise and separate the blobs better

[image]

Next we find contours and sum the blobs. Note the morph close did not "detach" all the connected blobs, so we filter using contour area. If the blob is greater than some minimum threshold, we count the blob as a double instead of a single. Here's the detected blobs

[image]
[image]

Result

> blobs: 325

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

image = cv2.imread('1.jpg')
mask = np.zeros(image.shape, dtype=np.uint8)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray,0,255,cv2.THRESH_OTSU + cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (7,7))
opening = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel, iterations=5)

cnts = cv2.findContours(opening, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]

blobs = 0
for c in cnts:
    area = cv2.contourArea(c)
    cv2.drawContours(mask, [c], -1, (36,255,12), -1)
    if area > 13000:
        blobs += 2
    else:
        blobs += 1

print('blobs:', blobs)

cv2.imshow('thresh', thresh)
cv2.imshow('opening', opening)
cv2.imshow('image', image)
cv2.imshow('mask', mask)
cv2.waitKey()
```