# Python: Counting number of objects inside a section of an image and label it with a determined color

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, label, image-segmentation

I am stuck here trying to develop a solution for my college project for a given an already segmented image (example attached, but unfortunately the link isn't appearing because I'm still new here), the idea on it is to label each one of these segmented squares from the image and count the number of the objects inside each one of these squares and define a color depending the square value counted:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EuH8n.jpg)

I couldn't able to find anything here similar to this question according to my doubts anywhere in the net. Anyone has any idea or a way to do it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: There might actually be a start to your problem, or something similar, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38619382/how-to-count-objects-in-image-using-python). There're a bunch of linked questions on the right hand side there as well that would be worth looking at!

My guess is the easiest way to do this would be to use Python to create separate images using each of those segmentations, then test each of those separate images using something similar to the linked question. :)

Comment: There's also [this question](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/9179/library-to-count-number-of-objects-in-image) and set of answers on the Data Science StackExchange. Think that might be more useful to you. :D

Comment: A potential approach is to threshold then perform contour area filtering to determine the objects. Could you add your input image so we can experiment?